# Altering xml string the easiest way

Tags: c#, xml, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm getting a fetchXml from an external source and I need to insert an attribute into it. At this moment I'm doing a Q&D by replacing an attribute that surely resides there by itself together with the one I'd like to add.

```
String fetchy = ...;
String surely = "<attribute name=\"entity_uno_id\" />";
String addity = "<attribute name=\"entity_duo_id\" />";
return fetchy.Replace(surely, surely + addity);
```

This is ugly and not professional. Can I redesign it in a safer way? I have no control over the fetchXml being served to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the fetchXml that your receiving, have them format it in a String.Format ready type of formatting.  For example, if your current string looks like this:

`var xml = "<blah><attribute name='entity_uno_id' /></blah>"`

change it to this:

`var xml = "<blah><attribute name='entity_uno_id' />{0}</blah>"`

then you can add whatever you want like this:

```
String fetchy = ...;
String addity = "<attribute name='entity_duo_id' />";
return String.Format(fetchy, addity);
```

### EDIT 1

Assuming you still have control over the fetch xml given to include the `{0}` in the correct location of the xml, this extension method would work:

```
public static string AddAttributes(this string fetchXml, params string[] attributeNames)
{
    return String.Format(fetchXml, String.Join(String.Empty, attributeNames.Select(a => "<attribute name='" + a + "' />")));
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I can't know for sure that the detectee is a fixed string. It could be *firstname*, *fullname* or even *crazydonkeyname*. Well, maybe not the last one but that'd definitely describe the nature of the assignment. Don't you just love when a customer tells you *what* to do **and** *how* to do it? I went with RegEx this time. Don't like it very much by it works for now. +1 for a good idea. Let's see if James pitches in too. I still remember our overkill discussion about late/early bound with diagrams. :)

Comment: @CRMconfusee I've added an extension method that allows you to add multiple attributes.  Does that help?

Comment: Oh, cool. That gave me quite a few ideas on how to resolve a few quirks I had. The extension thingy with *this* was a nice idea. Thanks!

Comment: Be carefull with that approach because if the xml string already contains {0} or {1} or whatever other format specifier when calling string.Format you may and up with a messed up xml or worse get a format exception as in that case string.Format("Asdasd {0} {1} asdas", 0);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 string xmlString = ... // the whole xml string;
    var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
    var xElement = new XElement(XName.Get("attribute", null));
    xElement.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("name", null), "entity_duo_id");
    xml.Add(xElement);
```